# How can I extract a file name from a grep result?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to get a list of all programs executed on system startup.

My game plan is as follows:

- `grep -r` the `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc.d/*` directories
- Search for any line that explicitly starts with "/"
- Include execution from backticks and $()
- Assume execution is performed by specifying full path and ignore relative path execution (i.e. `./...`)

To that end, I used the following:

```
egrep -r '^\s*/|\$\(\s*/|\`\s*/' /etc/rc.d/* /etc/init.d
```

Since it's searching files in the directories, the results list the file it was found in and the full line. I would like to now pipe the results into something to get just the file name and the pipe that into `sort|uniq` to get a simplified list. I think I can use awk somehow, but I am not so familiar with it.

Example Result:

```
/etc/init.d/foo:             foo=$(/bin/echo hello)
/etc/init.d/bar:             bar=$(/bin/echo world)
/etc/rc.d/init.d/foobar:     /bin/false
```

Desired Output:

```
/bin/echo
/bin/false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to the help from alb3rtobr, I was able to get it:

```
egrep -hor '(^\s*/|\$\(\s*/|\`\s*/)[^ ]*' /etc/rc.d/* /etc/init.d | sed -e 's/\($(\|)\|^\s*\)//g' | sort | uniq
```

I modified the egrep to continue matching until encountering a space and then added the `-o` option to return only the matched pattern. I also modified the sed to trim leading whitespace.

EDIT: Changed to match pattern while not a space character

Answer (score 2):

If you add -h option to egrep, filename will not be shown.

```
egrep -hr '^\s*/|\$\(\s*/|\`\s*/' /etc/rc.d/* /etc/init.d | sed -e 's/\($(\|)\)//g'
```

That sed regex will delete all the "$(" and ")"